# Sql modify record

Tags: sql, syntax

I have field in my sql table named 'content'.
I have 300 records in this table that contain the embeded code of a video, like:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1cmOCl3AAcs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can i add with sql the following code to this records like: class="main" .

Comment: Please add a sample record to your question.

Comment: Please specify what the resulting text should be in your example.

Comment: Are you trying to select records that have 'class="main"' in them or update some of the records so that they will have 'class="main"' in them? Further, it may help to list which flavor of SQL (e.g., MySQL, Oracle) you are using and whether you can access your DB with JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which DBMS you are using, you should be able to use the `replace` function:

```
update mytable set content=replace(content,"title","main=""class"" title")
where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest and most correct answer?  Don't store all of that.  The only unique part is the video id, in this case "1cm0c13aacs".  Store only that. When you retrieve it, generate the rest of that HTML around it on the fly.